# How to show the row names and column names for the Golf SVD example?

Tags: r, svd

I tried using R in IdeOne to display the SVD results from the [Single Value Decomposition (SVD) tutorial](http://www.puffinwarellc.com/index.php/news-and-articles/articles/30-singular-value-decomposition-tutorial.html) using the R code from [Dr. Jerry A Smith](http://datascientistinsights.com/2013/02/17/single-value-decomposition-a-golfers-tutotial/). The IdeOne link is [here](http://ideone.com/Yj3y6j), and here's what I ran:

```
scores<-c(4,4,3,4,4,3,4,2,5,4,5,3,5,4,5,4,4,5,5,5,2,4,4,4,3,4,5)
golfMatrix<-matrix(scores,nrow=9)
rownames(golfMatrix)<-c("Hole 1", "Hole 2", "Hole 3", "Hole 4", "Hole 5", "Hole 6", "Hole 7", "Hole 8", "Hole 9")
colnames(golfMatrix)<-c("Phil", "Tiger", "Vijay")
print (golfMatrix)
golfSVD<-svd(golfMatrix, nu=nrow(golfMatrix), nv=ncol(golfMatrix))
golfSVD
approx_Golf_1 <- golfSVD$u[,1] %*% t(golfSVD$v[,1]) * golfSVD$d[1]
print (approx_Golf_1)
```

the results I got the bottom didn't have the hole and player names like in Dr. Jerry A Smith's example:

```
[,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,] 3.954119 4.649399 4.347188
 [2,] 4.281532 5.034384 4.707149
 [3,] 2.429859 2.857118 2.671405
 [4,] 3.975401 4.674423 4.370586
 [5,] 3.647987 4.289438 4.010625
 [6,] 3.696949 4.347010 4.064454
 [7,] 3.341855 3.929477 3.674061
 [8,] 3.091084 3.634611 3.398361
 [9,] 4.559984 5.361798 5.013281
```

How do I modify the R code so I can display the hole names & player names?

Comment: Maybe he just set the names manually by
`rownames(approx_Golf_1) <- rownames(golfMatrix)`

Comment: @marco-k I should try that!